# SPARQL property path - Retrieve the closest node only

Tags: sparql, ontology, turtle-rdf

Suppose we have an ontology recording log events, with 2 distinct types of events: `info` and `warning`. Each entry is linked to the previous one via the non-transitive property `hasPreviousEvent` as shown below:

[image]

For all the `info` nodes I would like to retrieve the closest `error` node, no matter how many hops back it resides. Ideally, for the above sample dataset, I would like to have the following resultset:

| entry | prev |
| --- | --- |
| :info_2 | :error_1 |
| :info_3 | :error_2 |
| :info_4 | :error_2 |

Using SPARQL property paths, the following query

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
?entry rdf:type :Info ;
    :hasPreviousEntry* ?prev .
?prev rdf:type :Error .
} ORDER BY ?entry
```

reasonably retrieves the following resultset:

| entry | prev |
| --- | --- |
| :info_2 | :error_1 |
| :info_3 | :error_1 |
| :info_3 | :error_2 |
| :info_4 | :error_1 |
| :info_4 | :error_2 |

I cannot find how I could have the desired results. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that there doesn't exist another error linked by `?entry` which in turn links to `?prev` in at least one step.

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?entry rdf:type :Info ;
         :hasPreviousEntry* ?prev .
  ?prev rdf:type :Error .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?entry :hasPreviousEntry* [ rdf:type :Error ;
                                :hasPreviousEntry+ ?prev ] .
  }
} ORDER BY ?entry
```